# How does the client know the ephemeral port being used by the child TCP process?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, tcpclient, tcp

While reading up on how TCP works, I have read in quite a lot of books which mention that after `listen()`, when a client connects to the server, `accept()` should be called by the socket programmer to accept the connection from the client. The parent TCP server process (listening on port, lets say ,80) then calls a `fork()` and a child process will be created which will then continue communicating with the client. The child process will obviously have to bind to another ephemeral port to communicate with the client. My question is how will the client know which port to send the data to in order to communicate once the child process is forked? Does the parent TCP process listening on port 80 convey it to the client?

Comment: No, the `accept` call sets up the binding for the server-side. And the TCP connection contains the information about the client-side (address and port). The client will know the server-side port because the server have to *reply* to the connection request, and the TCP packet contains the port number of the server. [Read more about TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and especially about the [connection establishment and "three-way handshake"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No. The client *already* knows the server-side port, because it's the one it connected to. Nothing to do with the server reply whatsoever. The server reply logically consists of two bits, SYN and ACK. No other new information at all.

Comment: Hi Joachim. Thanks for the response. I understand the part you have mentioned. What I am looking forward to knowing is, how will the client know which (ephemeral) port will the child process be listening on once the 'accept()' (and the subsequent 'fork()', which creates the child process) occurs? In the 3 way handshake, will the SYN-ACK message contain the information about the ephemeral port? Please use Figure 4 for reference in the link below to understand better what I am trying to convey:
http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/socketprogramming.html

Comment: @EJP Ah yes, you're correct about that. It seems it was too long ago I did low-level networking stuff.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg For accuracy, no new information except the server's sequence number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hiw does the client know the ephemeral port being used by the child TCP process?

There is no ephemeral port to know. The client just keeps using the same target port that it conncted to.

> The child process will obviously have to bind to another ephemeral port to communicate with the client.

No. The client process inherits the accepted socket, which is bound to the same local port as the listening socket.

> My question is how will the client know which port to send the data to in order to communicate once the child process is forked?

It communicates via the same port it connected to.

> Does the parent TCP process listening on port 80 convey it to the client?

The client inherits the socket via the FD inheritance mechanism.